# polymer equivalent to ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

I am rewriting a page that is currently using an Angular 1 framework to polymer 1 (or 2). I don't know what the equivalent of ng-repeat is in polymer. This is what I have right now in Angular 1.

```
<div class="consultant"  ng-repeat="consultant in consultants | limitTo:i">
            <p>{{consultant.displayName}}</p>
            <p ng-if="consultant.phoneNumber != undefined" >☎ {{consultant.phoneNumber}}</p>
            <br ng-if="consultant.phoneNumber == undefined" />
            <p class="email" ng-if="consultant.email != undefined" ><span class="icon-envelope"></span><a href="mailto:{{consultant.email}}"> {{consultant.email}}</a></p>
            <br ng-if="consultant.email == undefined" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat) and probably [`dom-if`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if)

In your case this could look something like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[consultants]]" as="consultant">
  <div class="consultant">
    <p>[[consultant.displayname]]</p>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[consultant.phoneNumber]]">
      <p>☎ [[consultant.phoneNumber]]</p>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!consultant.phoneNumber]]"><br></template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[consultant.email]]">
      <p class="email">
        <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
        <a href="mailto:[[consultant.email]]">[[consultant.email]]</a>
      </p>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!consultant.email]]"><br></template>
  </div>
</template>
```